# Does .html() method automatically encode HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xss

**Context**

I have a website where users can write their own articles. I use a contenteditable div that allows users to mark up their HTML (bold, italicize, etc.), and I want to make sure I prevent XSS attacks. To do so, I use `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting data onto the page. I want to leave the user's input data alone and encode it on output. However, I use the `.html()` method to get the HTML content in the contenteditable div, and it seems that user-inserted tags are automatically encoded by the `.html()` method or the contenteditable div.

The structure of the contenteditable div is

```
<div class="article" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

As an example, if the user attempts to do XSS on the contenteditable div by inserting `<script>alert('hi')</script>`, like so:

```
<div class="article" contenteditable="true">
    <script>alert('hi')</script>
</div>
```

When I submit the data to the database (using `var article = $(".article").html();`), the data I see in the database isn't `<script>alert('hi')</script>`, but is instead `&lt;script&gt;alert('hi')&lt;/script&gt;` despite the fact that I didn't encode anything on my own. Then, I have to avoid using `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting the article content so that the div encodes the string back to its original form instead of staying encoded.

**Question**

Does the `.html()` method automatically encode HTML, and if so, how would one prevent this functionality (if that is advisable)?

Comment: `console.log` would answer this for you

Comment: @GetSet Good point. It does result in the same encoded characters. Do you know of any way to prevent this? Maybe I should revert it in the server-side code.

Comment: You could use a javascript function (sadly, not in-built, or is it these days? dunno) to do a "htmlchars decode". I could post it as an answer, although it's not my code. And the link to it has a new and "improved" way of doing it, but I like the old way and thus would post it as an answer, if you are interested.

Comment: Btw, on *Maybe I should revert it in the server-side code*, PHP does have their *htmlspecialchars_decode()* so thats a good idea too. The data has to go server-side anyway for storage correct? You could return the data decoded after your server does it's business.

Comment: @GetSet Yeah, I would take that answer! I would also mention that `.html()` does encode HTML? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Carson D, The following code has benefited me in my travels.

Here's the source link. As mentioned, they may have updated it to modern approaches. If you want just a stand-alone function then remove the `module.exports =` bit from the code in the link as follows:

https://locutus.io/php/strings/htmlspecialchars_decode/

It is possible that that link may become stale in SO's future history, so here is that code in code form with all credits given due. This is the code I used since at least 2013/14 so it may not indeed match the code in the link, but I believe the authors are the same.

```
function htmlspecialchars_decode (string, quoteStyle) { // eslint-disable-line camelcase
  //       discuss at: https://locutus.io/php/htmlspecialchars_decode/
  //      original by: Mirek Slugen
  //      improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (https://kvz.io)
  //      bugfixed by: Mateusz "loonquawl" Zalega
  //      bugfixed by: Onno Marsman (https://twitter.com/onnomarsman)
  //      bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (https://brett-zamir.me)
  //      bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (https://brett-zamir.me)
  //         input by: ReverseSyntax
  //         input by: Slawomir Kaniecki
  //         input by: Scott Cariss
  //         input by: Francois
  //         input by: Ratheous
  //         input by: Mailfaker (https://www.weedem.fr/)
  //       revised by: Kevin van Zonneveld (https://kvz.io)
  // reimplemented by: Brett Zamir (https://brett-zamir.me)
  //        example 1: htmlspecialchars_decode("<p>this -&gt; &quot;</p>", 'ENT_NOQUOTES')
  //        returns 1: '<p>this -> &quot;</p>'
  //        example 2: htmlspecialchars_decode("&amp;quot;")
  //        returns 2: '&quot;'

  var optTemp = 0
  var i = 0
  var noquotes = false

  if (typeof quoteStyle === 'undefined') {
    quoteStyle = 2
  }
  string = string.toString()
    .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
    .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
  var OPTS = {
    'ENT_NOQUOTES': 0,
    'ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE': 1,
    'ENT_HTML_QUOTE_DOUBLE': 2,
    'ENT_COMPAT': 2,
    'ENT_QUOTES': 3,
    'ENT_IGNORE': 4
  }
  if (quoteStyle === 0) {
    noquotes = true
  }
  if (typeof quoteStyle !== 'number') {
    // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags
    quoteStyle = [].concat(quoteStyle)
    for (i = 0; i < quoteStyle.length; i++) {
      // Resolve string input to bitwise e.g. 'PATHINFO_EXTENSION' becomes 4
      if (OPTS[quoteStyle[i]] === 0) {
        noquotes = true
      } else if (OPTS[quoteStyle[i]]) {
        optTemp = optTemp | OPTS[quoteStyle[i]]
      }
    }
    quoteStyle = optTemp
  }
  if (quoteStyle & OPTS.ENT_HTML_QUOTE_SINGLE) {
    // PHP doesn't currently escape if more than one 0, but it should:
    string = string.replace(/&#0*39;/g, "'")
    // This would also be useful here, but not a part of PHP:
    // string = string.replace(/&apos;|&#x0*27;/g, "'");
  }
  if (!noquotes) {
    string = string.replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
  }
  // Put this in last place to avoid escape being double-decoded
  string = string.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')

  return string
}
```